# Behaviour of solutions to ODE $\dot y(t)= Bh(y(t))$ from behaviour of solutions to ODE $\dot x(t) = h(x(t))$, if $B$ is positive definite

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $B$ is a positive definite $d \times d$ matrix. Then given the asymptotic behaviour of an o.d.e $\dot{x}(t) = h(x(t))$ where $h:\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$, will the asymptotic behaviour of the o.d.e $\dot y(t)= Bh(y(t))$ be same as the former o.d.e ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is no. Consider the unstable system 
$$\tag{1}
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dot x_1&=&x_2\\ \dot x_2&=&0
\end{array}\right.
$$
or 
$$
\dot x=Ax,\qquad A=\left( \begin{array}{ll} 0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right).
$$
Let
$$
B=\left( \begin{array}{rr} 2&-1\\-1&2\end{array}\right).
$$
One can see that the system
$$
\dot y= BAy,\qquad BA=\left( \begin{array}{rr} 0&2\\0&-1\end{array}\right)
$$
is stable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Suppose that $x^*$ is the globally asymptotically stable equilibrium of the former o.d.e (in the original problem), what can be said about the globally asymptotically stable equilibrium of the latter ?

Comment: @applied_math Nothing can be said in general. Consider, for example, the stability of the solutions of the systems $\dot x= Ax$, $A=\left( \begin{array}{rr} -5&-5\\4&3\end{array}\right)$ and $\dot y= BAy$, $B=\left( \begin{array}{ll} 1&1\\1&3\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Other than $B=I$, $I$=identity matrix, under what general case these two o.d.es can be compared.

Comment: @applied_math This is true when $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenbasis